# CSOM with Content Editor Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-2016

I followed this CSOM video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cr8wht3z_BA and created a script file.

```
<script src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='_layouts/15/sp.js'></script>
<script lang='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MicrosoftAjax.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.Core.debug.js" />
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {console.log('Init SP Client Context')});
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded('', 'sp.js');

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
console.log('web: ' + web);

</script>
```

But after loading it in a Content Editor Web Part, I get the following error.

```
Init SP Client Context
init.js?rev=iUHQ88pWz8HFvRXFm5n84A%3D%3DTAG0:1 Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function
    at ExecuteOrDelayUntilEventNotified (init.js?rev=iUHQ88pWz8HFvRXFm5n84A%3D%3DTAG0:1)
    at Object.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded [as executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded] (init.js?rev=iUHQ88pWz8HFvRXFm5n84A%3D%3DTAG0:1)
    at default.aspx:655
ExecuteOrDelayUntilEventNotified @ init.js?rev=iUHQ88pWz8HFvRXFm5n84A%3D%3DTAG0:1
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded @ init.js?rev=iUHQ88pWz8HFvRXFm5n84A%3D%3DTAG0:1
(anonymous) @ default.aspx:655
mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1 [Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMSubtreeModified' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.
bind @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
(anonymous) @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
MQueryResultSet.bind @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
MQueryResultSet.one @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
(anonymous) @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
(anonymous) @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
$_global_mquery @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
(anonymous) @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1 [Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeRemoved' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.
bind @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
(anonymous) @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
MQueryResultSet.bind @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
MQueryResultSet.one @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
(anonymous) @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
(anonymous) @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
$_global_mquery @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
(anonymous) @ mquery.js?rev=iT%2FLunFUsFugTeo%2FAjQL5Q%3D%3DTAG0:1
sp.ribbon.js?rev=Fl2mDCI2EuFibC1HILdAFw%3D%3DTAG0:2 Uncaught TypeError: this.$K_3.customFromJson is not a function
    at SP.Ribbon.CalendarListPageComponent.SP.Ribbon.ListViewWebPartPageComponent (sp.ribbon.js?rev=Fl2mDCI2EuFibC1HILdAFw%3D%3DTAG0:2)
    at Function.Type.initializeBase (ScriptResource.axd?d=0q0DXhSRHN48U2mYVoycVizcI6W7PYLDvhhWa-FBB_M6B98agZYZ5S8yIFX2lx4T0jifjCZeHY4O5hP2l0przC-Vw5fvi-LAbXEyVcolNdkqhBtKo62zHKPUyG0HM6OYZ5persFq-4Wm6WMlOhFP7OTKzCmOv6LzLZ4tTDoehSu6RIHrn9afYjBtTgPLm-oX0&t=ffffffffa580202a:5)
    at SP.Ribbon.CalendarListPageComponent.SP.Ribbon.GenericListWebPartPageComponent (sp.ribbon.js?rev=Fl2mDCI2EuFibC1HILdAFw%3D%3DTAG0:2)
    at Function.Type.initializeBase (ScriptResource.axd?d=0q0DXhSRHN48U2mYVoycVizcI6W7PYLDvhhWa-FBB_M6B98agZYZ5S8yIFX2lx4T0jifjCZeHY4O5hP2l0przC-Vw5fvi-LAbXEyVcolNdkqhBtKo62zHKPUyG0HM6OYZ5persFq-4Wm6WMlOhFP7OTKzCmOv6LzLZ4tTDoehSu6RIHrn9afYjBtTgPLm-oX0&t=ffffffffa580202a:5)
    at new SP.Ribbon.CalendarListPageComponent (sp.ribbon.js?rev=Fl2mDCI2EuFibC1HILdAFw%3D%3DTAG0:2)
    at _initTRAWebPartWPQ4 (default.aspx:1224)
    at NotifyEventAndExecuteWaitingJobs (init.js?rev=iUHQ88pWz8HFvRXFm5n84A%3D%3DTAG0:1)
    at NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs (init.js?rev=iUHQ88pWz8HFvRXFm5n84A%3D%3DTAG0:1)
    at sp.ribbon.js?rev=Fl2mDCI2EuFibC1HILdAFw%3D%3DTAG0:2
```

The video is for SP2013, but my environment is 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
///<script type='text/javascript' src='_layouts/15/sp.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
<script lang='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {console.log('Init SP Client Context')});
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded('', 'sp.js');

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
console.log('web: ' + web);

</script>
```

The script can be inserted into script editor/content editor webpart directly.

[How to Add JavaScript code to a Page using the Script Editor Web Part](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000265208-how-to-add-javascript-code-to-a-page-using-the-script-editor-web-part)

Comment: Thank you for reply but now I get `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'get_current' of undefined or null reference` on `var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();`

Comment: This most cause by SharePoint js not load correctly or custom js execute before SharePoint js load completely. Just testing the script in a SharePoint webpart page/wiki page.